# Assigning DateTime value from variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to swap 2 DateTime variables in my view model from my controller but they won't get assigned.

More specifically, when I inspect the model just before it gets returned, the values are swapped but the resulting view does not reflect the swap in the input boxes

**Here is the view model**

```
namespace ClubLocator.Models.ViewModels.ProspectDetail
{
    public class ProspectViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Prospect> Prospects { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> SearchBy { get; set; }
        public string SelectedSearchBy { get; set; }
        public string SearchString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Here is the controller code:**

```
[...]
int result = DateTime.Compare((DateTime) p.DateFrom, (DateTime) p.DateTo);

//1st date is larger so swap them
if (result >= 1)
{
    DateTime? _tmpDateTo = new DateTime();
    _tmpDateTo = p.DateTo;
    model.DateTo = p.DateFrom;
    model.DateFrom = _tmpDateTo;
}

return(model);
```

Comment: No clue where p is coming from so kinda hard to guess. Also: _tmpDateTo  = new DateTime(), and right after that you overwrite the value with p.DateTo, whats the use of that ?

Comment: model.DateTo = p.DateFrom; model.DateFrom = p.DateTo; The rest of the code is superfluous. You are just juggling your variables back n forth

Comment: In addition to the good points above, you're misusing DateTime.Compare. It only guarantees that the result will be greater than zero, not exactly one, if the first date is greater.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `DataAnnotations` to enforce that the DateFrom is less than or equal to the DateTo? And, this can be reflected onto the user interface as well, so the user is aware that they have created an illogical situation (From comes after the To). It's better than silently correcting the mistake.

Comment: Oren is right, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx

Comment: Good catch, guys thanks. I changed the compare to >=1. Our users tend to be older so I like to avoid frustrating them with error messages; that was my thinking behind silently doing the swap

Comment: The solution here is to clear the modelstate before returning the model.  Any changes made to the model are overridden by that.  so use ModelState.Clear() before you return your view and all should be well.